# Memory leak _bstr_t reallocation

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm new to C/C++ and memory management

I got memory leak in program and using Visual Leak Detector to find.

```
_bstr_t record = "";

for (int rownum = 0; rownum < num_rows; ++rownum) {
    const int num_cols = PQnfields(res2);

    for (int colnum = 0; colnum < num_cols; ++colnum) {
        if (PQgetisnull(res2, rownum, colnum) == 0) {
            string data = PQgetvalue(res2, rownum, colnum);
            record = record + data.c_str();
        }
        else
        {
            record = record + L"<NULL>";
        }

        if (colnum + 1 < num_cols) {
            record = record + "#";
        }
    }
    recordMap[rownum] = record;
    PQclear(res2);
}
```

And it point out that line `record = record + data.c_str();` make memory leak.

I tried to `::SysFreeString(record)` but not work

Any method to do it?

Comment: What is a `bstr_t`?

Comment: @Shawn My mistake . It should be `_bstr_t`

Comment: Same question. Is it something you wrote, from a library, what?

Comment: @Shawn, yes it is from library

Comment: It would help to mention which one...

Comment: @Shawn it's a Microsoft thing. And I suspect the actual leak is in not freeing a pointer returned by `PQgetvalue`, because `_bstr_t` is like a smart pointer.

Comment: Yes, it exactly from Microsoft : comutil.h - Native C++ compiler COM support - BSTR, VARIANT wrappers header
*

Comment: @MarkRansom. Could you help me  how to `freeing a pointer returned by PQgetvalue` .

Comment: If I knew what `PQgetvalue` was, I could. You left that out of your question. Or maybe you could just check the documentation for it yourself?

Comment: @MarkRansom https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/libpq-exec.html. It is function of Postgresql library. I tried to clear `PQclear(res2);` but seem not enough

Comment: I see from the documentation that `PQclear` is indeed the proper way to free that pointer, so the problem must lie elsewhere; my intuition was invalid. I apologize. I believe though that the methods of `_bstr_t` can be entered via the debugger so that you can detect what they're actually doing, maybe you can discover the leak that way.

Comment: I see nothing in this code that should be leaking. I would suspect a bug in Visual Leak Detector before I suspect a bug in `_bstr_t`. However, I do question where `res2` is initialized, and why it is being cleared on each loop iteration without being reinitialized each time. Also, shouldn't the declaration of `record` be moved inside the outer loop so each `recordMap[rownum]` gets a clean string, not a continuation of previous rows?

Comment: Where exactly does VLD show a leak? Show entire call stack please. Also it's a good idea to check with another profiler, e.g. Deleaker.

Answer (score -1):

I think the memory leak happens in `bstr_t` assignment operator or + operator. You should check there.

Comment: Hi @Quy Phan. I think so but I dont known how to fix here, could you help me a suggestion?

Comment: Try to replace it by record += data.c_str();
Not sure if it works, but I will help you further if it's not.

Comment: Thinking is good, too few people seem to do it, but knowing is better. To make this a good answer, you would explain why you think this and offer suggestions on how to fix it.